# Ignoring nbextensions Metadata and run statistics + output in ipynb files when collaborating (e.g. via git)

Tags: git, jupyter

When collaboratively working on jupyter notebooks with git, we often have the problem of people forgetting to remove the outputs (i.e. `Restart Kernel and Clear all outputs`) before they commit their changes. This results in many differences, 97% rewrites (plots are a lot of text) etc. - twice, as of course we somehow have to revert those things as well.

Additionally some of us use some nbextensions which write lots of things into the `metadata` section of the *cells*, here an example:

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "## Very Simple Markdown\n",
    "Just to demonstrate the problem."
   ]
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 3
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.5.1"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 0
}
```

With toggled heading from one of the default plugins (another cool feature is execution timing which produces similar things):

```
   "metadata": {
    "heading_collapsed": true
   },
```

Is there a way to exclude the metadata and the outputs easily when saving files, or some command for jupyter to clean those things up? Or is it possible to tell jupyter to save such things somewhere locally? Or do I have to come up with my own script to "cleanup" the notebooks before I commit them?